# Redux Changes URL on State Change During API Call

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I am having a problem with an async API call. When I do the API call (similar to the redux real-world example - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/middleware/api.js):

```js
const actionWith = data => {
  const finalAction = Object.assign({}, action, data)
  delete finalAction[CALL_API]
  return finalAction
}

const [requestType, successType, failureType] = types
next(actionWith({
  type: requestType
}))

return API.post(apiName, path, myInit).then(
  response => next(actionWith({
    response,
    type: successType
  })), error => next(actionWith({
    type: failureType,
    error: error.message || 'Something bad happened in API call'
  }))
)
```

jMy page gets completly reloaded which leads to a Cross-Origin problem which makes my API call failing. If I execute the API call seperately everything works out fine. Though in combination with the async redux state handling I am running into problems. 
My action looks like this:

```js
export const UPDATE_DEVICE_REQUEST = 'UPDATE_DEVICE_REQUEST'
export const UPDATE_DEVICE_SUCCESS = 'UPDATE_DEVICE_SUCCESS'
export const UPDATE_DEVICE_FAILURE = 'UPDATE_DEVICE_FAILURE'

const updateDevice = (id, updatedConfiguration) => ({
  [CALL_API]: {
    types: [UPDATE_DEVICE_REQUEST, UPDATE_DEVICE_SUCCESS, UPDATE_DEVICE_FAILURE],
    apiName: 'PlayerAPI',
    path: '/device/1',
    method: 'post',
    myInit: {
      headers: {},
      body: {},
      response: true
    }
  }
})
```

And in my reducer I already tried multiple things with the state but never really got a working solution:

```js
case UPDATE_DEVICE_REQUEST:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: true
  })
case UPDATE_DEVICE_FAILURE:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: false
  })
case UPDATE_DEVICE_SUCCESS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: false
  })
```

Do you have an idea what my problem might be? In the logs I do not see any indication why he is doing a complete page reload. 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is not working. I also don't understand what you are doing. please reformat your question

Answer (score 0):

So now I found the exact problem and the solution. 
It seems that my form was triggering a reload of the page every time the button in the form was clicked.

Either I removed the ... or used event.preventDefault() in the function which is called by the button (also compare https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1510).

Due to this weird reload mechanism my API call never went through.

Comment: What's weird about it? That's how form controls work: they submit forms unless you tell them not to.